# Проверка логина при регистрации

Tags: php

```
if (strlen($login) < 3 || strlen($login) > 16 || preg_match("![A-Za-z]!i",$login) && preg_match("![А-Яа-я]!i",$login)) {
    $errorlogin3 = 'Длина логина от 3 до 16 символов. Вы можете использовать максимум 2 пробела. Нельзя использовать цифры и чередовать латиницу с кириллицей.';
    $_SESSION['errorlogin3'] = $errorlogin3; 
    header('Location: saveUser');   
} 
else {
    echo "успешно";
    //setcookie("login", $login, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
    //header('Location: saveUser');
}
```

Помогите, нужно, чтобы в логине было не больше чем 2 пробела и полностью запретить ввод числа.

Comment: Сделайте за меня, здесь так не работает, смотри в сторону регулярных выражений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Комбинируйте как хотите:

`!preg_match('#^[a-z0-9 ]+$#i', $login)` - только английские, цифры и пробелы

`!preg_match('#^[а-яё0-9 ]+$#iu', $login)` - только русские, цифры и пробелы

`mb_strlen($login) < 3` - не меньше 3 символов

`mb_strlen($login) > 16` - не больше 16 символов

`substr_count($login, ' ') > 2` - не больше двух пробелов

---

P.S. возможно можно запихать это все дело в одну регулярку, но как-то потно.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает. А как можно полностью запретить ввод цифр?

Comment: @dddd ну например если используете `!preg_match('#^[a-z0-9 ]+$#i', $login)` то убрать `0-9`, если хотите отдельной регуляркой, то `preg_match('#[0-9]+#', $login)` - выдаст `TRUE` если обнаружены цифры.

Comment: @dddd и на будущее, если ответ вас устроил и проблема решена, то поставьте соответствующую галочку, это и другим поможет сэкономить время и не заглядывать сюда, и будет стимулом в дальнейшем вам помогать.